# What if Delayed Choice Quantum Eraser is actually predicting/affecting which way the idler photons will go?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-eraser

I understand there is no FTL and retrocausality.

Let's say we have detectors D1 and D2 that have already recorded the following patterns:

[image: 1]

Then we send a new photon and the signal photon lands on this position of D0, which is the same place that D1 has a peak recording and D2 has a valley:

[image: 3]

Does it mean the idler photon will more likely land on D1, but not D2?
If not, why do people say the subset of D0 which the idler photons land on D1, has a same pattern of D1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't detect the interference patterns at D1 - D4. The detectors only give you clicks. In the experiment you only change the position of D0 which gives you "the pattern at D0" understood as the probability distribution to detect photon at D0 as a function of its position $x$.

Now, the pictures you give (R01 and R02) are joint probabilities to detect photons at D0 and D1 / D2 as a function of D0 position. I will call it $P(D0_x\cap D1)$. From that we can get the conditional probabilities you are interested in,
\begin{equation}
P(D1| D0_x)=\frac{P(D0_x\cap D1)}{P(D0_x)},\quad P(D2| D0_x)=\frac{P(D0_x\cap D2)}{P(D0_x)}
\end{equation}
Obviously, you get it right. If you detect the signal photon at D0 located at that point you may predict that the idler would go to D1.

This kind of "magic" is nothing more than predicting the color of the sock looking at the other sock in the pair and knowing that they have the same colors.

Now, this "which way" information corresponds only to the D1 and D2 shoulders. In this case the state of the idler actually is the superposition of it going through the left and the right slit. I.e. in this case you have $P(D3|D0_x)=P(D4|D0_x)$.

That's because in the quantum case when you look at the black sock you know only that the other one in the pair was in the state $|\text{black}\rangle$ (when they were separated from their package, before any manipulations were done). And it may be that $|\text{black}\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Big(|\text{short}\rangle+|\text{long}\rangle\Big)$ so this information gives you only the probabilities for the experiments with the other sock.

It may be useful to note that if you don't care about joint probabilities i.e. about correlations, and consider data for each detector separately you will get the same stuff no matter how you change your experiment with respect to the other photon in pair. You may turn off detectors D1 - D4, completely throw out all the mirrors and detectors that do something with the idler photon, process the idler in some complicated fashion, $P(D0_x)$ will not be affected. E.g. if you combine mutually exclusive R01 and R02 or if you combine R03 and R04 you will get (up to the scaling) the same picture D0 (that corresponds to $P(D0_x)$ irrespective to what happens with the idler) Likewise you may throw out D0 to the garbage can, $P(D1)$ will not be affected.

As to your question "why do people say the subset of D0 which the idler photons land on D1, has a same pattern of D1?"... As you can see in that experiment the only "pattern of D1" we have IS the subset of D0 for which the idler photons land on D1 (i.e. $P(D0_x|D1)\sim P(D0_x\cap D0)$ i.e. R01) People say all kind of stuff about this experiment and this explains its enormous $\frac{\text{fame}}{\text{usefulness}}$ ratio.